How to get AMPLITUDE in Opus player android by using AudioManager or AudioTrack in Android
I'm using OpusPlayer to play an audio where I need to get the Amplitude.
we can get Amplitude if using MediaRecorder by mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() but in OpusPlayer I'm only using audioManager and AudioTrack. Now unable to get the Amplitude.
Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Finally I got this by using buffer size and shortData while reading the file
for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
            sum += audioData[i] * audioData[i];
        }
double rms = Math.sqrt((double) sum / bufferSize);



Returns the maximum absolute amplitude that was sampled since the last call to this method. Call this only after the setAudioSource().
MediaRecorder Docs

Unfortunately, you must keep track of the amplitude yourself as you play the Audio, as with getMaxAmplitude it seems the value is not preprocessed but updated continuously. Since amplitude is universally measured in decibels (dB) you can use the getStreamVolumeDb in AudioManager to keep track.
Further implementation help
